# Use of the 'being' formulation

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is this sentence correct ? If not, what would be the correct formulation ?

```
Being designed for « Best-effort » encoding (low slack time), 
DVFS is therefore hard to apply on this type of components
```

Regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably grammatical to use *being* here, but quite unnecessary. I would simply say: *Designed for "best-effort" encoding...DVFS is hard to apply...*.

There are a couple of other problems with your sentence. From the type of quotation marks you are using I deduce that you may be French. In this type of use, which does not involve quoting someone's speech, word for word, we do not normally use a capital letter.

You do not need the word 'therefore' and it sticks out a bit awkwardly. It is clearly implied from what you are saying.

'Component' needs to be singular, otherwise one would say 'on these type of components'.

Comment: You guessed right about my mother tongue ! I'll take care of these mistakes ! Thanks !